# Scrollable Tile View in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have the follwoing way to have tile view of any grid size. But I want only 2x3 tiles on the page and 2x1 on the below the visible part of the page. Which you can access only after scrolling the page. But I am not able to achieve this by the below method.

I tried scroll view for the whole view.xml but then it got shrunk to the top of the page. And I don't have any control on the size of tiles. The change according to the view.

view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you test this layout structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:fillViewport="true" add this property inside scrollview

Comment: Thanks for answer. I did check. But It's not working. It is showing 4x2 gird on the main page. I want 3x2 grid on main page and when I scroll up, it should show the below two as well. Does your answer works for you? Just try and see...

Comment: @ArewegoodQ do you want to have simple Grid layout as xml or using GridView?

Comment: Anything is fine. I want scrollable tile view, where tiles should be buttons. So that I can get some activity on pressing them.